# The “0” key is not working on my keyboard but “Shift” + “0” works for “)”

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

My 0 key on the keyboard is not working. But the ) is working with shift.

I tried a brand new keyboard, it's the same.

It's a software issue.

I tried the OSK and it's not working there either.

I tried to uninstall the driver and reboot, still the same.

Any idea?

Comment: Still no luck :(